# How do I correctly use HttpClient with async/await?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm getting two errors for the following code:

```
public async Task<string> TestDownloadTask()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        response = await client.GetStringAsync("?concept_tags=True&api_key=DEMO_KEY");
    }

    return response.Content;
}
```

I'm getting:

- Cannot await 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' on the "await" line
- Cannot convert expression type 'System.Net.Http.Content' to return type 'string'

I've been attempting to write the above code that will download a string from a web service, but there seems to be a lot of conflicting information about how to use async and await and how to use HttpClient and I do not know what is wrong with the code I've written.

Where am I going wrong and how should I be doing it instead?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that is the error you're getting? `GetStringAsync` returns a `Task<string>`, and you're trying to assign the result to a variable of type `HttpResponseMessage`, so your code is definitely broken because of type mismatch, but it seems highly unlikely you'd get an error saying "Cannot await `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`".

Answer (score 12):

This method `client.GetStringAsync` returns `Task<string>`

```
public Task<string> TestDownloadTask()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // You don't need await here
        return client.GetStringAsync("?concept_tags=True&api_key=DEMO_KEY");
    }
}
```

To use above function:

```
public async void SomeMethod()
{
    // await to get string content
    string mystring = await TestDownloadTask();
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, is HttpResponseMessage not needed?

Comment: Yes. You don't need HttpResponseMessage, GetStringAsync return string

Comment: @user9993 `HttpResponseMessage` isn't a magic incantation. If you're getting an `HttpResponseMessage` from any methods you invoke and you need to store it in a variable, then you need a `HttpResponseMessage` variable. Otherwise you don't need one.

Comment: @Asad True, it's just the poor and conflicting information on the internet is making it difficult to understand.

Comment: I'm getting Cannot convert expression type System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> to return type string

Comment: @user9993 One of the nice things about using a statically typed language is that you can use the type system itself as documentation (if you have a good IDE, like Visual Studio), and ignore online docs. If you right click `GetStringAsync` and select go to definition, you should be able to see what the method wants and what it returns.

Comment: @user9993 Did you add an `await` to the code given in this answer?

Comment: Good point, I added await to the return and now I get Cannot await System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string

Comment: @Asad do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: @user9993 Why did you add an `await`? You need to understand what you're doing (i.e what Tasks are, how requests and responses work, how async/await works) otherwise it's all just meaningless symbols that you're randomly manipulating until you get something that works.

Comment: Because then VS says the code will run synchronously, which is against what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @user9993 Right, this code is supposed to be synchronous. It doesn't do anything asynchronously; it instantiates an `HttpClient` (synchronously), configures a few things on this instance (synchronously), then starts off a request and returns a `Task` that represents a deferred result for that asynchronous request (synchronously). The code in this method is all synchronous, so you don't need async or await. Just return the `Task` you get from `GetStringAsync`. It is possible that there are methods that call this one that need to be asynchronous, but `TestDownloadTask` certainly isn't.

Answer (score 3):

Change either to

```
return await client.GetStringAsync("?concept_tags=True&api_key=DEMO_KEY");
```

or to

```
return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: What is the difference and when should one be used over the other?

Comment: `response.Content` is of type `HttpContent` which can represent not only string, but e.g., a byte array if you want to download a file. In your case no difference.