# Api ends up empty results - C#

Tags: c#, api

I'm making an app with an Api , using C# but in my app I get invalid request while, with the same api url, it gives me the correct results in postman. Anyone know why this happens?

```
http://api.tradeskillmaster.com/v1/item/EU/ragnaros/82800?format=json&apiKey=****
```

using that api url with the following code:

```
HttpClient Connection = new HttpClient();
//Connection.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.tradeskillmaster.com/v1/item/EU/" + Realm.Text.ToString() + "?format=json" + "&&" + "apiKey=" + apiKey.Text.ToString());

Connection.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.tradeskillmaster.com/v1/item/EU/ragnaros/82800?
    format=json&apiKey=v-dtTQX6uBDOsWDUs6SWgYUBOXvyqxRd");

HttpResponseMessage response = Connection.GetAsync("api/emp").Result;
//var emp = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Results>>().Result;
var emp = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

debugLabel.Text = emp;

dataGridView1.Show();
dataGridView1.DataSource = emp;
```

Does anyone know why I get invalid when I run my app? Am I missing some code?

Comment: Look at each request in Fiddler and see how they're different.

Comment: You seem to have omitted some of the code. Where's the part that sends the request to the API?

Comment: @Stijn This is all I'm using, I'm using windows forms so `dataGridView1.DataSource = emp;`
Is the code that should show results in the app by adding htem to the gridview

Comment: It can't be. Where does `response` come from?

Comment: And the relation between `Connection` and `response` is...?

Comment: @Stijn You're right, I accidentally deleted a part of the code while I tried to delete the comments, I'll add them to my question ^^

Comment: Why aren't you `await`ing?

Comment: You're setting the `BaseAddress` to include a querystring, then requesting `api/emp` on top of that?  Also FWIW you've left your api key in when you re-pasted your code.  If you really want it hidden, as well as editing it out you'd best mod-flag the post so they can redact it from the post history.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I never exactly understood that part though haha

Comment: Can you show the actual full URL you've used within postman?  If if's the first one in your post, what is `api/emp` even doing there in your code?

Comment: @john to make sure it has time to connect? very good point, how would I add an await in there?

Comment: Rick [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31102843/3181933)

Answer (score 2):

The request URL is not correct. By setting `BaseAddress` to `http://api.tradeskillmaster.com/v1/item/EU/ragnaros/82800?format=json&apiKey=...` and doing a `GetAsync` to `api/emp`, you end up with a request to `http://api.tradeskillmaster.com/v1/item/EU/ragnaros/api/emp`. You can see this with the debugger:

[image: screenshot of debugging info]

`BaseAddress` should be the part that doesn't change, and the parameter for `GetAsync` should be the part that changes, **relative** to `BaseAddress`.

Comment: How do you get such a detailed debugger? I'm using visual studio 2017

Comment: Hover the `response` variable while you are stopped at a breakpoint (placed after the line you want to inspect). Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger if you want to learn how to debug properly.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you...

```
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = client.GetAsync("http://api.tradeskillmaster.com/v1/item/EU/ragnaros/82800?format=json&apiKey=test").Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<yourobject>(result.Result);
                    return resultObject;
                }
            }
```