# Does these HttpClient call be called in parallel?

Tags: c#, httpclient, asp.net-core-2.2

I've a .NET Core web app that, once a web method (i.e. Test()) is invoked, call another remote api.

Basically, I do it this way (here's a POST example, called within a web method Test()):

```
public T PostRead<T>(string baseAddress, string url, out bool succeded, object entity = null)
{
    T returnValue = default(T);
    succeded = false;

    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", MyApiKey);
            HttpResponseMessage res = null;
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity);
            var body = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var task = Task.Run(() => client.PostAsync($"{baseAddress}/{url}", body));
            task.Wait();
            res = task.Result;
            succeded = res.IsSuccessStatusCode;

            if (succeded)
            {
                returnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            }
            else
            {
                Log($"PostRead failed, error: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res)}");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log($"PostRead error: {baseAddress}/{url} entity: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity)}");
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

Question is: if Test() in my Web App is called 10 times, in parallel, do the POST requests to the remote server are be called in parallel or in serial?

Because if they will be called in serial, the last one will take the time of the previous ones, and that's not what I want.

In fact, when I have huge list of requests, I often receive the message *A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond*.

Comment: Can I ask why you are not fully async? Why bother with `Task.Run` & then not `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`? If your `PostRead` method would be async, you could call `PostRead` in parrallel, with `Task.WaitAll`. Also, shouldn't `HttpClient` really be injected and reused throughout your application (you would only once have to manipulate the defaultheaders and api key)

Comment: **PLEASE read**: [You're (probably still) using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/). Then: get rid of `Task.Run` and use `async` and `await` correctly, you're just wasting threads for no good reason instead of letting ASP.NET Core manage them efficiently. As for the actual question, there's no `lock` here so I have no clue what makes you think they would run in serial

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto is this a correct use to use it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/31102831/365251

Comment: No - any time you see `new HttpClient` is wrong, except in the most extremely simple applications where it's going to happen once every minutes/hours. HttpClient instances need to be reused. As for the async part, yes, that example is good

Comment: To answer your question nothing is running asynchronously here perse unless you are doing it in the implementation. As to your error, you need to watch out because you might be getting throttled even at your current rate. I doubt running things concurrently will help your current error. Also, as noted, there are better ways to use httpclient, namely IHttpClientFactory, and letting it all `async`

Comment: I've managed HttpClient as you suggested, but still the SocketException error. I've opened a detaild question here, if you want give it a try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69850197/httpclient-azure-and-system-net-sockets-socketexception-what-to-do

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto if you Place an answer, you got accepted by me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Question is: if Test() in my Web App is called 10 times, in parallel, do the POST requests to the remote server are be called in parallel or in serial?

They will be called  in parallel. Nothing in the code would make it in a blocking way.

> In fact, when I have huge list of requests, I often receive the message A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

There are at least 2 things that need to be fixed here:

- Properly using `async`/`await`
- Properly using `HttpClient`

The first one is easy:

```
public async Task<T> PostRead<T>(string baseAddress, string url, out bool succeded, object entity = null)
{
    succeded = false;

    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", MyApiKey);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity);
            var body = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var responseMessage = await client.PostAsync($"{baseAddress}/{url}", body);
            var responseContent = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                succeeded = true;
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>();
            }
            else
            {
                // log...
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log...
    }

    return default; // or default(T) depending on the c# version
}
```

The second one is a bit more tricky and can quite possibly be the cause of the problems you're seeing. Generally, unless you have some very specific scenario, `new HttpClient()` is plain wrong. It wastes resources, hides dependencies and prevents mocking. The correct way to do this is by using `IHttpClientFactory`, which can be very easily abstracted by using the `AddHttpClient` extension methods when registering the service.

Basically, this would look like this:

```
services.AddHttpClient<YourClassName>(x => 
{
    x.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    x.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", MyApiKey);
}
```

Then it's a matter of getting rid of all `using HttpClient` in the class and just:

```
private readonly HttpClient _client;

public MyClassName(HttpClient client) { _client = client; }

public async Task<T> PostRead<T>(string url, out bool succeded, object entity = null)
{
    succeded = false;

    try
    {
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity);
        var responseMessage = await _client.PostAsync($"{baseAddress}/{url}", body);
        //...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log...
    }

    return default; // or default(T) depending on the c# version
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [HttpClient call using  parallel and solve JSON Parse error]

You can use task. when for parallel call . but when you use  N number of calls and try to parse as JSON   this may throw an error because result concatenation change the Json format   so we can use Jarray. merge  for combining the result .

---

#### Code

```bash
public async Task < string > (string baseAddress, string url, out bool succeded, object entity = null) {

  using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {

    string responseContent = string.Empty;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", MyApiKey);
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity);
    var body = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var tasks = new List < Task < string >> ();

    var jArrayResponse = new JArray();

    int count = 10; // number of call required
    for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
      async Task < string > RemoteCall() {
        var response = await client.PostAsync($"{baseAddress}/{url}", body);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      }

      tasks.Add(RemoteCall());
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    foreach(var task in tasks) {
      string postResponse = await task;

      if (postResponse != "[]") {
        var userJArray = JArray.Parse(postResponse);
        jArrayResponse.Merge(userJArray);

      }

    }
    responseContent = jArrayResponse.ToString();

    return responseContent;

  }

}
```