# HttpClient, Azure and System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: what to do?

Tags: c#, azure, httpclient, .net-core-2.2

We are getting lots of problems on a Web App in Azure, which use HttpClient to make remote call to a endpoint.

I was aware it was a problem with outbounds connections limit in Azure, so I refactored the code using only one instance of HttpClient with singleton pattern.

Here's my helper:

```
public class HttpClientHelper
{
    string ApiKey = "";
    static HttpClient httpClient;
    
    public HttpClientHelper(IConfiguration config)
    {            
        var appsettings = config.GetSection("AppSettings");
        ApiKey = appsettings.GetChildren().Where(x => x.Key == "URL").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        
        if (httpClient == null)
        {
            httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", ApiKey);
        }
    }

    public async Task<T> SingleRead<T>(string baseAddress, string url)
    {
        T returnValue = default(T);
        
        try
        {
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{baseAddress}/{url}").ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var r = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                returnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(r);
            }
            else
            {
                Log($"SingleRead failed, error: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response)}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex, $"SingleRead ex: {baseAddress}/{url}");
            throw ex;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }

    public async Task<T> PostRead<T>(string baseAddress, string url, object entity = null)
    {
        T returnValue = default(T);            

        try
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity);
            var body = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"{baseAddress}/{url}", body).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var r = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                returnValue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(r);
            }
            else
            {
                Log($"PostRead failed, error: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response)}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex, $"PostRead url: {baseAddress}/{url} entity: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity)}");
            throw ex;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

And than I do basic request calling SingleRead() (for GET) or PostRead() (for POST).

The problem is that still, sometimes, I get SocketException:

[image]

Here's the fullstack trace:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
   at MobilityServer.Helpers.HttpClientHelper+<PostRead>d__4`1.MoveNext (MobilityServer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: c:\MyProject\WebApp\Helpers\HttpClientHelper.cs:77)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at MobilityServer.Helpers.MigrationHelper+<GetLdcHeaders>d__8.MoveNext (MobilityServer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: c:\MyProject\WebApp\Helpers\MigrationHelper.cs:54)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at MobilityServer.Controllers.AndroidController+<GetLdcHeaders>d__8.MoveNext (MobilityServer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: c:\MyProject\WebApp\Controllers\BasicController.cs:104)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor+<Execute>d__0.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeActionMethodAsync>d__12.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker+<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__23.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__18.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__16.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware+<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=2.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=2.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
Eccezione interna System.Net.Sockets.SocketException gestita in MobilityServer.Helpers.HttpClientHelper+<PostRead>d__4`1.MoveNext:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper+<ConnectAsync>d__2.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
```

And this the Exception Stack Trace:

```
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at MobilityServer.Helpers.HttpClientHelper.PostRead[T](String baseAddress, String url, Object entity) in c:\MyProject\WebApp\Helpers\HttpClientHelper.cs:line 63
```

I don't get where the problem can be.
The outbound connections now are lower than the service plan (which is "S3 : 2").

SNAT seems way down the limit:

[image]

The same for the outbound connections:

[image]

(note: I've resized from 3 instances to 2 yesterday at 21:30, that's why those green "drop").

I really can't get what's going on. The environment sames correctly setup.

Any clues?

**EDIT**
Here's the version (i.e. the edits) to add the suggested IHttpClientFactory:

```
// Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);            
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTIONSTRING"]);
    services.AddHttpClient<MigrationHelper>();
}

public class MigrationHelper
{
    HttpClientHelper httpc;

    public MigrationHelper(IConfiguration config, HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        // ...
        
        httpc = new HttpClientHelper(config, httpClient);
    }
}

public class HttpClientHelper
{
    string ApiKey = "";
    HttpClient httpClient;
    
    public HttpClientHelper(IConfiguration config, HttpClient _httpClient)
    {
        var appsettings = config.GetSection("AppSettings");
        ApiKey = appsettings.GetChildren().Where(x => x.Key == "URL").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        
        httpClient = _httpClient;
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", ApiKey);
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

Still doesn't works, and I got the same error Socket messages. Here's a full example:

```
{
    "Message": "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond",
    "Data": {},
    "InnerException": {
        "ClassName": "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException",
        "Message": "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond",
        "Data": null,
        "InnerException": null,
        "HelpURL": null,
        "StackTraceString": " at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)",
        "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
        "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
        "ExceptionMethod": null,
        "HResult": -2147467259,
        "Source": "System.Private.CoreLib",
        "WatsonBuckets": null,
        "NativeErrorCode": 10060
    },
    "StackTrace": " at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()\r\n at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()\r\n at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()\r\n at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)\r\n at MobilityServer.Helpers.HttpClientHelper.PostRead[T](String baseAddress, String url, Object entity) in c:\\MyProject\\WebApp\\Helpers\\HttpClientHelper.cs:line 60",
    "HelpLink": null,
    "Source": "System.Net.Http",
    "HResult": -2147467259
}
```

Comment: Using HttpClient this way is wrong. Instead of creating your own class use HttpClientFactory and `services.AddHttpClient` to configure,register and *recycle* SocketHttpClientHandler instances as needed. Using a single HttpClient instance avoids socket exhaustion BUT if there are any DNS or load balancer changes, the cached sockets will be pointing to a non-existent server

Comment: Which .NET (Core) version are you using? Methods like [GetFromJsonAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.getfromjsonasync?view=net-5.0) and [PostAsJsonAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpclientjsonextensions.postasjsonasync?view=net-5.0) could help remove most if not all of the extra code

Comment: You can also configure API keys and retry login in AddHttpClient [using named or typed HttpClients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) and Polly.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using .NET Core 2.2. I can switch to HttpClientFactory, but sure this is the problem?

Comment: Check [Use IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests). The issues described are exactly what you encountered. Besides, it's always easier to solve problems by *reducing* custom code, especially if it replicates built-in functionality. As the article explains, using HttpClientFactory allows using retry logic. HTTP calls can always fail for a multiple of reasons

Comment: BTW you didn't post the full exception so it's unclear what the actual problem is. `HttpRequestException` just says the request failed. There's no message, no inner exceptions. Perhaps it's related to sockets, perhaps the remote server failed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've take the exception from Azure Application Insights. I've added another extract added by my internal log: is it enough?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos meanwhile, I'm trying to implement the IHttpClientFactory, and let see. Later I'll post my new code, so you can also check it

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos implemented IHttpClientFactory as you suggested, but nothing change, as I guess :(

Comment: I suggested posting the actual full exception, not just the stack trace. It's still unclear what the error is beyond the type name: `HttpRequestException`. Post the actual full exception string returned by `Exception.ToString()` and the actual code. If the error is caused by a transient *remote* problem, you may be able to overcome it by retrying the request. If the remote server crashes on high load you'll have to throttle your calls. If the server returns a 429 it means you made too many concurrent requests and got throttled

Comment: By using HttpClientFactory you can handle the actual error, eg retry after a delay if you got a 500 error or a 429

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238906/discussion-between-markzzz-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos added the edited version of the code, plus the StackTrace as you suggested.

Comment: This is a connection timeout. That's exactly what would happen if there was a network change and the client ended up with a socket pointing nowhere. You need to retry the call. You can use the Polly policies described in [Implement HTTP call retries with exponential backoff with IHttpClientFactory and Polly policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-http-call-retries-exponential-backoff-polly) to make this transparent to callers

Comment: Your code is not configuring the HttpClient *in AddHttpClient* though, it still tries to configure it after the fact. The ApiKey isn't going to change so why not set it just once? [This example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#named-clients-1) configures the default request headers in AddHttpClient: `services.AddHttpClient<MigrationHelper>(c=>{ var apiKey=Configuration.....; c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", ApiKey);});`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos network change so often? It happens every 3-4 minutes. Can it be?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos also: if it take 21 seconds the first time, if I retry, it will take 21+N seconds for a request? Does it makes sense at all? Isn't better to "understand" why this happens? Can't believe there is somethings like 40/50 network changes every hour :(

Comment: Or the remote service lost its connection. We can't guess what the network infrastructure and services *you* used behave this way. There's no relevant information. The only information is code that can be eliminated entirely and an exception that says the remote service didn't respond. Maybe it froze. Maybe it crashed. Maybe it uses an unreliable wireless connection. We can't know. Things like this happen on the Internet all the time. Unless you know why that remote service behaves this way, all you can do is retry

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos nope man. The problem is from Azure. If I do the same requests flow from another server to the same remote endpoint, I don't see any 500/SocketExceptions :(

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos wow man! I've reduced the app instances from the service Plan from 3 to 1 and BOOM: all errors are vanished :O how can it be? HttpClient mess requested with multi instances on Azure?

Comment: @markzzz chances are the instances share the same baremetal. So you'll have the total allowed socket connections / number of instances.

Answer (score 0):

Try 1: The maximum you can do in your app is to use IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests).

Try 2: When you scale out the endpoint (if it is in your control) there's a Load Balancer over all your instances, so, traffic is automatically load balanced between them. Maybe you need a better load balancing solution (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/load-balancing-overview).

Try 3: If your app works better on a single machine, you should scale up and use per-app scaling (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-scale-per-app)

Try 4: Troubleshooting intermittent outbound connection errors in Azure App Service (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-intermittent-outbound-connection-errors)

P.S.: a wild guess is that the endpoint could not handle the increasing requests from your 3 instances (an instance has a limit of 256 concurrent connections (per server endpoint) allowed when making requests using an HttpClient object set via HttpClientHandler.MaxConnectionsPerServer property); that's why when you decrease the number of instances it behaves better

Comment: What do you mean with "If your app works better on a single service plan"? Its of course within a service Plan. In this case, a single app, with 2 slots (and I'm using it on a particolar slot).

Comment: Maybe is an Azure problem.Your apps are running on a standard serviceplan and the problem seems to appear (gets worse) when the number of instance goes up. So I would try to use a premium service plan and try (using per-app scaling) to have multi instance on the same serviceplan. Maybe the load balancing is not so good on a standard serviceplan

Comment: why premium would be better? Also now I have multi instances on the same service Plan, if I set "manual instances" to a value higher than 1, right?

Comment: sorry, i was trying to say the same machine; when you scale out (let's say 3 instances), behind your serviceplan there are 3 machines, each one running one instance of your app; if you need the scale out to 3 for other apps running on the same serviceplan, via per-app scaling, you can control how many instance this app can have (the other apps will remain to 3 instance) or you should try the p2v2:2 serviceplan

Comment: the problem is back :( Even with a 1 instance on App Service Plan (S3:1), which cointains only that single App (on 3 different slots). I really don't know how to do more...! Can be that slot can introduce others problems?